Compiling threaded FFTW3 for Windows via WSL/MinGW
I've been trying to use the multithreaded version of FFTW with fftw_init_threads() etc. After downloading the zip from the windows FFTW page, I tried using these functions but VS2022 said the symbols were unresolved. I looked into installing from source, and ran this command on Ubuntu WSL with MinGW installed :
./configure --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-avx --enable-avx2 --disable-fortran --enable-avx512 --enable-generic-simd128 --enable-generic-simd256 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-float

followed by make and make install, as stated here. The process generates the DLL for the library. To use this with VS I also need a .lib (or a .def file as per the windows tutorial) file and I couldn't find this anywhere after the make install. Not sure how to make progress from here.

Worth checking to see if you can get this from vcpkg or whatever Visual Studio uses as a package manager, don't use Visual Studio that much, and not have to screw around building it yourself.

@user4581301 you're onto something with this, thank you. Just gave it a quick check and found https://vcpkg.io/en/package/fftw3. I'll keep this open just in case I want other custom options, but this is a great solution. +1

Unless you are absolutely wedded to MinGW I really wouldn't use it on Windows for heavy numerical work - the default system libraries use x87 code. Unless things have changed very recently that makes it a poor choice for anything using sin/cos/exp etc. See MinGW using x87 code for cos, exp & sin. If it has changed recently please let me know. I switched to native ggc on Linux Unbuntu to get full performance FP code. Intel ICX is about the fastest on Windows.

@MartinBrown It's not that I'm wedded to it - just that FFTW recommends it, but they say themselves that they don't know much about windows. Would you be able to point me in the right direction for installing it by other means than MinGW?

Sorry - not really. I haven't used FFTW for quite a while now. FWIW I reckon the Intel ICX compiler generates better FP code at least for the stuff that I do - but all the modern compilers are very good. I suspect that there is a way to switch to full SIMD libraries in MinGW but I never figured out how to do it and/or by now it might have been fixed. Slow sin/cos may not be much of a handicap for FFTW anyway since it generates most trig functions by recurrence relations.
